# Printing Multiple Files in one Print Job

Tags: command-line, printing

I have a program that will output timesheets as separate .xps files into a folder. I am looking for a way to use the command line to print all of these files at the same time. Since there could be hundreds of these files it is also important that they be printed as one print job so that other documents aren't printed in the middle of them.

I have been searching on and off for about two months for a way to do this. So far I have come up with nothing. I would appreciate any advice on how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting my files to PDFs. Then I downloaded pdftk which is a command-line tool that can be used to combine multiple PDF files into one. Now I can just run pdftk and then print the combined file. It's unfortunate that there is not a better way to handle this in Windows but at least it works.